# Can I use count function on PBDS ordered set after changing it to muliset by changing one of the template less<int> to less_equal<int>

Tags: c++, count, c++17, multiset

In my code it's showing some kind of error , if there is any other way please let me know.

Comment: How you can change set to multi set?

Answer (score 0):

A `tree<int, null_type,less_equal<int>, rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update>` is not a multi set. It is ill-formed. `less_equal` does not meet the requirement [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

You should use [`std::multiset<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)

Comment: I  think you get it wrong , actually I am using `tree<int, null_type,less<int>, rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update>` .......... instead of `less<int>` , I am using `less_equal<int>`

Comment: @Supandeepsingh Oh. There is no multi_set with `__gnu_pdbs`. You still have to use something that satisfies *Compare*